# How can I use Go's built in server in production without the port number?

Tags: ubuntu

I am using Go on Ubuntu and my main .go file contains this:

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```

This works fine. I can get to the app with example.com:8080. Also, I can use Nginx with `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;` to access the app at example.com. But how can I use the app at example.com without Nginx?

If there is a way, is this recommended?

Comment: Did you intend to run the application standalone, without any web server installed, or did you intend to run it in addition to the web server, available on http://example.com/ whilst all other web sites are still available?

Comment: Yes standalone application

Comment: If you tell it to use :80 (or any port number less than 1024) you have to start it as root, and then hopefully drop privileges. It is not recommended to run applications in production in this manner, but to use a reverse proxy, which gives you some needed things like logging, isolation, ability to easily scale (static content, possibility of hardware ssl termination), various plug-ins such as mod_security or authcz plugins, ability to support multiple applications on the one up/port and enhanced integration with any existing deployment practice. Also useful has been the ability to edit headers

Answer (score 3):

Change the binding from `"*:8080"` to `":80"`.

Comment: Of course, this only works if nothing else (like nginx or Apache) is already using port 80.

Comment: That's true; but if there is another server listening on port 80, that can be configured to proxy through to the existing server. I read the question as to how to use it without using a proxy server.

Comment: But we also know from the question that Nginx is there and we should trust that the OP is smart enough to uninstall it when trying to get rid of it.

Comment: This does require that EITHER the application starts as root and drops privileges (which may be an issue, according to https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13838) OR the process is starting with the Linux capability CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE --- see capabilities(7)